# Tracking resource allocation across multiple projects - GitHub?

Tags: team-management, resource-planning, distributed-team, github-issues, zenhub

I have an agile development team of 20-25, and we use GitHub (Enterprise) for repo, backlog etc and ZenHub for enhanced Kanban boards. I would like all members to be able to easily set their allocations per project, easily, and as often as it changes. If there was an add-on for GitHub that would allow that type of tracking that would perfect, but am open to any tools. Thanks!

Comment: I think this requires a bit more context - do you have a single team of 20-25 members? How many projects are they working on, and how often do these allocations change?

Comment: Yes our organization (team) is usually around 20-25 members. Can be up to 20ish projects going on at any given time, and allocations can change often, potentially week to week.

Answer (score 1):

Anton - I had a very similar problem. I ended up building out a platform to help with project forecasting. It has some light CRM features and some light time entry features but we'll be enhancing those in the coming weeks and months. Specifically, it will help you:

- Keep track of pipeline projects
- Forecast out time associated with a specific role and allow you to assign one of your people
- Keep track of your team's allocation across all of their projects

https://taliscape.com/

There aren't integrations into any kind of kanban boards but that is

Give it a whirl and let me know if this will solve your problem. If not - let us know what features you need and we can bake those into the platform.